# Valid (?) JSON data causing errors in Django, must be served to frontend as string and converted by JSON.parse() in javascript - why?

Tags: python, json, django, character-encoding, jsonparser

I have a JSON file hosted locally in my Django directory. It is fetched from that file to a view in *views.py*, where it is read in like so:

```
def Stops(request):
   json_data = open(finders.find('JSON/myjson.json'))
   data1 = json.load(json_data)  # deserialises it
   data2 = json.dumps(data1)  # json formatted string
   json_data.close()
   return JsonResponse(data2, safe=False)
```

Using JsonResponse without (safe=False) returns the following error:

```
TypeError: In order to allow non-dict objects to be serialized set the safe parameter to False.
```

Similarly, using json.loads(json_data.read()) instead of json.load gives this error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

This is confusing to me - I have validated the JSON using an online validator. When the JSON is sent to the frontend with safe=False, the resulting object that arrives is a string, even after calling .json() on it in javascript like so:

```
fetch("/json").then(response => {
     return response.json();
     }).then(data => {
     console.log("data ", data); <---- This logs a string to console
...
```

However going another step and calling JSON.parse() on the string converts the object to a JSON object that I can use as intended

```
       data = JSON.parse(data);
       console.log("jsonData", data); <---- This logs a JSON object to console
```

But this solution doesn't strike me as a complete one.

At this point I believe the most likely thing is that there is something wrong with the source JSON - (in the file character encoding?) Either that or json.dumps() is not doing what I think it should, or I am not understanding the Django API's JSONresponse function in a way I'm not aware of...

I've reached the limit of my knowledge on this subject. If you have any wisdom to impart, I would really appreciate it.

EDIT: As in the answer below by Abdul, I was reformatting the JSON into a string with the json.dumps(data1) line

Working code looks like:

```
def Stops(request):
   json_data = open(finders.find('JSON/myjson.json'))
   data = json.load(json_data)  # deserialises it
   json_data.close()
   return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)  # pass the python object here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see the following lines of your code:

```
json_data = open(finders.find('JSON/myjson.json'))
data1 = json.load(json_data)  # deserialises it
data2 = json.dumps(data1)  # json formatted string
```

You open a file and get a file pointer in `json_data`, parse it's content and get a python object in `data1` and then turn it *back* into a *JSON string* and store it into `data2`. Somewhat redundant right? Next you pass this JSON string to `JsonResponse` which will further try to serialize it into JSON!! Meaning you then get a string inside a string in JSON.

Try the following code instead:

```
def Stops(request):
   json_data = open(finders.find('JSON/myjson.json'))
   data = json.load(json_data)  # deserialises it
   json_data.close()
   return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)  # pass the python object here
```

---

> **Note**: function names in python should ideally be in `snake_case` not `PascalCase`, hence instead of `Stops` you should use `stops`. See
> [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python
> Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Yes indeed, you caught it! Thanks a million for taking the time to help out with my silly error (I'll work on making smarter errors in future!)